# W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for notiang

Tags: java, android, json

I know that there are several questions posted on here with the same topic and error, but none of them indicate the same problem as mine, so I decided to post my question here, hoping that someone would help me point out the cause. Here's the code:

```
 private void showEmployee(String json){
        try {

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONObject c = jsonObject.getJSONObject(Config.TAG_JSON_ARRAY);
            Log.e("result",json);
            if(c!=null) {
                idwo=c.getString("id");
                String notiangs = c.getString(Config.TAG_NOTIANG);
                String alamats = c.getString(Config.TAG_ALAMAT);
                String gardus = c.getString(Config.TAG_GARDU);
                String penyulangs = c.getString(Config.TAG_PENYULANG);
                String lats = c.getString(Config.TAG_GPSLAT);
                String lons = c.getString(Config.TAG_GPSLON);
                String kettings = c.getString(Config.TAG_JUMLAHKETTING);

                notiang.setText(notiangs);
                alamat.setText(alamats);
                gardu.setText(gardus);
                penyulang.setText(penyulangs);
                lat.setText(lats);
                lon.setText(lons);
                ketting.setText(kettings);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And this is the JSON response:

```
 E/result: {"result":{"0":"3","id":"3","1":"abc1235gvv","no_tiang":"abc1235gvv","2":"JTM","jenis_tiang":"JTM","3":"","jumlah_ketting":"","4":"Mangkurayat","alamat":"Mangkurayat","5":"Cilawu","kecamatan":"Cilawu","6":"4555","kodepos":"4555","7":"Jawa Barat","provinsi":"Jawa Barat","8":"Kabupaten Garut","kota":"Kabupaten Garut","9":"adghc","penyulang":"adghc","10":"","gardu":"","11":"2017-05-01 08:49:49","tanggal":"2017-05-01 08:49:49","12":"107.88593833333334","lat":"107.88593833333334","13":"-7.249803333333333","lon":"-7.249803333333333"}}
```

So apparently there is a value for notiang, but I still got this warning in my logcat:

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for notiang
```

Answer (score 4):

The error is so clear it says you cannot convert `JSONArray` to `JSONObject` then you need to change this line

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
```

to this

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
```

and then in a `for` loop get `JSONObject` of the index and do whatever you want

for determining your object whether is `JSONArray` or `JSONObject` you can do this

```
String data = "{ ... }";
Object json = new JSONTokener(data).nextValue();
if (json instanceof JSONObject)
  //you have an object
else if (json instanceof JSONArray)
  //you have an array
```

Comment: what should we do when we don`t know our JSON will be object or array?

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting a json object, while you are getting an array of json objects.

Answer (score 0):

Change this Line

```
JSONObject c = jsonObject.getJSONObject(Config.TAG_JSON_ARRAY);
```

To

```
JSONArray peoples = null;

peoples = jsonObject .getJSONArray("Your Array Name/Tag);
```

The problem is your result have json array and your are trying it to convert to Json Object.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            Log.e("result",json);
            if(c!=null) {
                idwo=c.getString("id");
                String notiangs = c.getString(Config.TAG_NOTIANG);
                String alamats = c.getString(Config.TAG_ALAMAT);

                notiang.setText(notiangs);
                alamat.setText(alamats);

            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try{

JSONArray jArray= null;

jArray= jsonObject .getJSONArray("Key name);
}catch(Exception e){

}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation on how this code snippet is solving the OPs problem.